# Loop through dictionary + multiplying all the values

Tags: c#, loops, dictionary

I have a Dictionary (dict), which contains string (key) and double (value). I want to make this kind of math:

```
X = (A * B * ... * n) / ((A * B * ... * n) + ((1 - A) * (1 - B) * ... * (1-n)))
```

where A, B, ..., n is the value from my Dictionary.

```
foreach (var number in dict)
{
    A = number.Value;

    X = (A) / (A * (1 - A));
}
```

Comment: Thats nice. So what is the question?

Comment: What isn't working exactly? Are you just missing the `+=` operator (or similar)? (`X += (A)...`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
                Dictionary<int, int> dict = new Dictionary<int, int>();
                dict.Add(1, 10);
                dict.Add(2, 20);
                dict.Add(3, 30);
                dict.Add(4, 40);

                double coe1 = 1;
                double series = 1;
                foreach (var number in dict)
                {
                    coe1 *= number.Value;
                    series *= (1 - number.Value);
                }

                double x = coe1 / (coe1 + series);
```

and if you need intermediate results:

```
                foreach (var number in dict)
                {
                    coe1 *= number.Value;
                    series *= (1 - number.Value);
                    Console.WriteLine(coe1 / (coe1 + series));
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you would have them in a dictionary if you want to iterate over the values like this, but here you go:

```
Func<double, double, double> multiply = (v1, v2) => v1 * v2;

var product = dict.Values.Aggregate(1, multiply);
var diffProduct = dict.Values.Select(v => 1 - v).Aggregate(1, multiply);
var result = 1 / (1 + diffProduct / product);
```

I've simplified the overall expression a bit here so it loses less precision.

Comment: @Downvoter, could you please comment on what is incorrect here? Thanks.